# How to save code samples/snippet in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is it possible to save code samples/snippets in SQL Server 2005?

Actually I want to  maintain the font style and all of code, provided by user on website same as in stackoverflow we can provide code samples along with question.

Which data type should I use and what html control should i use to receive value from user?

I don't want to create a separate file to save code samples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO code snippets are text, with formatting applied by markdown. That is, format isn't stored...

Comment: hi gbn, thanks, that means i cant save samples in sql server, i must use files to store code samples provided by user?????

Comment: Maybe, if you store as raw data eg as html. I can't be more exact than that sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server Management Studio, you can use one of the often overlooked features : the Template Explorer:

[image]

As you can see from my screenshot, you can tap into a vast array of pre-defined scripts and templates, **and** you can create your own folders and templates, too - and use them (also share them in your team).